# PayPal payment initialization is failing through Cybersource

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

We are trying to make first PayPal payment initialization request through Cybersource and failing with 10002 code. I have asked Cybersource support to provide details and they said that PayPal itself gives internal server error. I want to make sure that we have setup all accounts correctly.

So we have setup test Cybersource merchant account and we have linked it to PayPal developer account X which has 2 sandbox accounts: X-facilitator@... and X-buyer@... . We have given 3rd party permission (cybersource_paypal_api1.cybersource.com) to X-facilitator and enabled Express Checkout and all other options to allow Cybersource to make PayPal payments on behalf of X-facilitator merchant account.Is there anything else that I need to setup? I suspect that we should link not the X developer account to the Cybersource, but X-facilitator@.. merchant account. Am I right? 
The reason I am asking here is trying to find quick solution, because we have spend already lot's of days on supports and meetings without finding the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PayPal 10002 is an authentication error, double check your API credentials and environment. If you are using sandbox credentials in live or vice versa it will not work.

https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&id=FAQ1030&actp=LIST

Comment: Thanks the reason was that I have linked test Cybersource account to PayPal real account not to sandbox account